# Coroutine being execute twice after starting, stopping, starting again

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a coroutine that I'm using to animate a cursor.  The coroutine looks like this

```
private IEnumerator AnimateCursor(Vector2 targetScreenPoint)
{
   while (true)
   {
      // Do animation stuff          

      Debug.Log(targetScreenPoint.ToString());
      yield return null;
   }
}
```

Everything works fine the first time I start the coroutine.  If the cursor moves, I call `StopCoroutine("AnimateCursor")` to stop the coroutine, and then start the coroutine again with a new value for the `targetScreenPoint` parameter.

When I start the coroutine again, the animated cursor still gets drawn in its original position and the `Debug.Log` prints both the first and second values of `targetScreenPoint` (which is why I think the coroutine is executing twice during each update loop).

If I replace `StopCoroutine("AnimateCursor")` with `StopAllCoroutines()`, it works correctly and the second time the coroutine starts, it only prints the second value of `targetScreenPoint`.

Does anyone know what's going on?

EDIT: I was wrong about the cursor still animating while the debugger is running.  I think the problem is with my `StopCoroutine`, but I don't know why.  Is there a special way that I have to stop a coroutine if the coroutine takes parameters?

Comment: Could you please post the code where you `StartCoroutine("AnimateCursor");`. I suspect you may accidentally start it, let's say you put it in a loop or `Update()` and they did something that you weren't aware of.

Comment: I'm sure `StartCoroutine` is only getting called twice.  I've stepped through with the debugger and it only hits that line twice.  I edited my original question because I was wrong about the animation stopping after I call `StopCoroutine`.

Comment: Just to be sure, you use `StartCoroutine("AnimateCursor", targetScreenPoint);` (string variance) don't you? Because `StopCoroutine("AnimateCursor")` only works if you use that string variance. If you use `StartCoroutine(AnimateCursor(targetScreenPoint));` it won't.

Comment: Ok, that explains it then.  I do StartCoroutine(AnimateCursor(targetScreenPoint));  Thank you.  I'll mark that as the answer if you want to post it.

Comment: I will make it an answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `StartCoroutine("AnimateCursor", targetScreenPoint);` - string variance.

Because `StopCoroutine("AnimateCursor")` only works if you use that string variance.

If you use `StartCoroutine(AnimateCursor(targetScreenPoint));` - IEnumerator variance - then there is no way you can stop your coroutine.

Answer (score -1):

The selected as "correct" answer is incorrect. 
[StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) returns type [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) which [StopCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) can accept as an alternate overload to stop a Coroutine.

In example:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Not that it makes any sense to start a Coroutine just to stop it...
    /// </summary>
    public void StartAndThenImmediatlyStopCoroutine()
    {
        Coroutine coroutine = StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine());
        StopCoroutine(coroutine);
        Coroutine anotherCoroutineExample = StartCoroutine("MyCoroutine");//Ewww... String based co-routine starting. This breaks Find All References in Visual Studios so you can't actually know where it's being called.
        StopCoroutine(anotherCoroutineExample);
        Coroutine evenMoreCoroutine = StartCoroutine(MyCoroutineWithParamaters(1, 2.2f, "Paramater Routines Rock!!!"));
        StopCoroutine(evenMoreCoroutine);
    }

    public IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    }

    public IEnumerator MyCoroutineWithParamaters(int myNumber, float myFloat, string myString)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    }
```

Comment: I added the link, but I could not find the overload that takes Coroutine as argument. Please post the link in he comments and I'll edit it in.

Comment: Looks like someone edited it in. If if was you Arkadiy thanks!